# npm ERR This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

It happens when I try to start server. This is probably not a problem with `npm`. There is likely additional logging output above.

I got everything updated and still same.

```
 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
      throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/Mateusz/Documents/reactWebsite/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! redux-simple-starter@1.0.0 start: `node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the redux-simple-starter@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Mateusz/.npm/_logs/2020-02-20T09_12_14_220Z-debug.log`enter code here`
```

Comment: delete the node modules and try installing the packages again

Comment: i already did it.

Comment: can you share your package.json file??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the why this error occurs, but I once got this error and solved through the following steps:

1. Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
2. Run `npm install`
3. Start the server again

Answer (score 0):

node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod

use this it may fixed for me it fixed